# Rails 2.3.4 unable to start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server

I have installed rvm and started with ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.4 along with rails 3.0.5 and ruby 1.9.2.Now when i use ruby 1.8.7 and try to start the server using

```
script/server
```

I am unable to 
Error :

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems   /custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- aws/s3 (MissingSourceFile)
from /home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/config/environment.rb:13
from /home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
from /home/Ghost/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/wantsa/vendor/rails/railties/lib/commands/server.rb:84
from /home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
from /home/Ghost/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
from script/server:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is kinda obvious, isn't it?

```
in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- aws/s3 (MissingSourceFile)
```

You don't have aws-s3 gem installed. Just install it:

```
gem install aws-s3
```

I'm pretty sure there will be other "missing" gems. Each ruby version in rvm has its own gem repository, so you have to reinstall all gems you need for ruby 1.8.7.

**UPDATE**: if you need earlier version of the gem (for example version 0.5.0):

```
gem install aws-s3 -v0.5
```

You have to require specific version of gem in rails, or it will automatically pick the latest version. Alternatively you can uninstall later version(s):

```
gem uninstall aws-s3
```

Comment: .but the problem is it installs the latest version .so shall compatibility issue come up...

Comment: @GhostRider I updated the post on how to install and remove specific gem versions

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you gems aren't installed properly for your ruby 1.8.7 install, or you have gems installed that are not compatible with 1.8.7 and/or rails 2.3.4.

Comment: .i think i installed some gems and may be the latest version has been installed which are incompatible .so shall i remove them